# Groovy files from a plugin

Tags: maven, grails, maven-plugin, grails-plugin

I want to know if it's possible to get the groovy files in place of the .class files of a plugin.

The scenario is as follows:

- The system uses some plugins (made by the company);
- These plugins use another and another...

it's something like this:

```
-> GenericSystem
  -> PluginA
  -> PluginB
    -> Plugin1
      -> PluginBase
```

In Grails 5 plugin classes are accessible in .class, but I would like to know if it is possible to generate .groovy instead of .class.

It would be interesting to have the .groovy files instead of the .class so that, if maintenance is needed in plugins, the developer can test the project without having to generate a new version of the plugin.

I tried to find something in the grails documentation or on the internet, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It would be interesting to have the .groovy files instead of the
> .class so that, if maintenance is needed in plugins, the developer can
> test the project without having to generate a new version of the
> plugin.

Our plugin system is not setup to support that.  A well designed plugin will provide options for customizing and testing the behavior of the plugin, but not by way of providing source code instead of bytecode.  The bytecode has to be provided, and is what will be loaded by the plugin runtime system.